# Ioptionmonitor to follow changes of appsettings

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to follow appsettings in real time. I use IOptionMonitor because I want to get changes in real time. I inject it to class which I did as singleton. 
In startup I wrote this

```
services.Configure<AppSettings>(_config.GetSection("appSettings"));
```

That's all. Some resources say to need to set follow code (delegate)  in class Programm in method ConfigureAppConfiguration

```
config.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
```

But it works for me without this. Did I correct understood that "reloadOnChange" doesn't need anymore? My current platform .net core 2.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The project templates for ASP.NET Core 2.2 use [`WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.webhost.createdefaultbuilder?view=aspnetcore-2.2), which sets this up for you out of the box. Here's the relevant code from the implementation of `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder` ([source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/2.2/src/DefaultBuilder/src/WebHost.cs#L169)):

```
config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
      .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
```

As this code shows, `reloadOnChange` *is* set to `true`, which is why it works without you having to do anything.